# Ассемблер/C++ как вызвать функцию пользовательского класса класса?

Tags: c++, классы, ассемблер, функции

Допустим у меня есть модуль/класс: TGAImage, а внутри него функция:

```
bool TGAImage::set(int x, int y, TGAColor c) {
if (!data || x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= width || y >= height) {
    return false;
}
```

И у меня есть процедура в ассемблере, куда передается указатель на конкретный экземпляр TGAImage, как из ассемблера вызвать эту функцию?
Я пока предполагаю лишь один способ: передавать адрес функции и прыгать на него, но функция же из другого модуля. Компилирую для win 32

Comment: Зависит ли системы. Почитайте про соглашения о вызове. К тому же, зависит еще от разрядности приложения

Comment: Проще всего так: напишите вызов, который вам интересует, на C++, скомпилируйте в ассемблерный код (компиляторы обычно такое умеют, поищите в настройках), и увидите, как производится вызов на вашей системе.

Comment: @VladD В том-то и дело, что адрес вызова всегда динамичный! Я же взываю функцию у конкретного экземпляра.

Comment: @Careviolan: Эээ, а код на C++, думаете, делает что-то другое? Он ведь тоже вызывает функцию у конкретного экземпляра.